# Why the Simple-Present "closes" in "thousands will see the exhibit by the time it closes"?

Tags: tenses, future

Consider the sentence:

> Thousands of people *will see* the art exhibit by the time it *closes*.

The first part of this sentence is in Future Simple, which seems correct as it is something to be completed in the future. But I wonder how to explain the "closes" at the end of sentence.

Comment: Your tenses don't seem right here. I'd use "*will have seen ... by the time it closes*" or *"will see … before it closes*" here.

Comment: @PeterShor could you explain why you pair these two choices?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other languages, English uses a present tense in subordinate clauses of this sort, even though they have future meaning.

One way of explaining this is by noting that English arguably has no true future tense, and the present is really a "non-past tense", which can have future meaning (eg *I leave tomorrow*). But that is not the whole of the explanation, because the so-called "future" with *will* is not grammatical in this sort of context: you can't say *by the time it will close*.

Beyond that half-explanation, I am afraid the answer is just that that is how English works.

[You can also use the present perfect in this context, where French, for example, would use the future perfect: *by the time it has closed*. I don't find any distinction of meaning between *by the time it closes* and *by the time it has closed*.]

Comment: For some reason which I cannot fathom, and although I am not one of nature's linguists, I never had the same problem grasping the fact that in French the tenses must match. Speakers of other languages really do seem to find English impossibly awkward on this particular score.